# try-with-resources: self-suppression not permitted

Tags: java, exception

Using **Jedis** to queue some data and running into this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted
>       at java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable.java:1043)

Block in question:

```
try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
   ... do things with redis
} catch(Exception exception) {
    LOG.error("exception", exception);
}
```

*Something* in the try-block is throwing an exception but I can't seem to get the message as this "self-suppression" happens.

Is there some way to extract the exception? And what is this message telling me?

Comment: I think it's telling you that `jedis.close()` is also throwing an exception. Ordinarily, that exception would get suppressed -- basically just added to the original exception, via `originalException.addSuppressed(exceptionFromClose)`. But if `jedis.close()` throws the same exception instance that the original exception threw, you would get that error.

Comment: Hm, took a quick peak at the code, and it doesn't seem to do that. What logging framework are you using? Could it be that LOG.error re-throws the exception you pass it?

Comment: Just for reference, here's [`Throwable.addSuppressed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-) and the specification for [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1). This perhaps doesn't help you solve the problem but it explains what the message is trying to say.

Comment: Why don't you caught trhowable? so you could look all